# What is the difference between large numeric values with attr "names" and Named num in R?

Tags: r, types

[image]

As the pictures shows, I need to get a input as depth1, I generated an Named num array as depth2 but it doesn't work for the input (would cause error..)

Comment: what is the error

Comment: @rawr "Error in if (all(sign(colors) >= 0)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> <Anonymous>"   actually no value is 0, all positive values.

Comment: seems like colors has NA values, `sum(is.na(colors))`

Comment: @rawr sum(is.na(depth1))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(depth2))
[1] 0

Comment: But what about your color vector? your if else references colors not depth1 or 2

Comment: @NotThatKindODr color is identical as depth2.

Comment: does depth1 have a weird typeof() or class()

Comment: Nope.. @NotThatKindODr

Comment: can you dput(depth1) and add it to your question along with the if-else code?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's unclear what code you are actually running. Also it's unclear if the problem is just with how RStudio is displaying the variable or if it's the object itself. A reproducible example would clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved finally. I checked the input, it's because the rownames I output with triple quote marks somehow, thus RStudio could recognize & convert it correctly but Rmarkdown engine can't.. To this issue, named Num related to that rownames..